# Prove or disprove $g \circ f $ is one-one $\to$ both $f$ and $g$ are one-one

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or disprove $g \circ f $ is one-one $\implies$ both $f$  and $g$ are one-one (if $g \circ f $ exists).

> I've got $g \circ f $ is one-one $\implies$  $f$  is  one-one (If we assume $f$  is  not one-one ,then we'll arrive at the conclusion that $g \circ f $ is not one-one by using definition of 1-1)
>
> But I can't prove or disprove   $g \circ f $ is one-one $\implies$  $g$  is  one-one.
>
> Plz Help...

Comment: please use \implies for $\implies$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last claim is not true.

For a counterexample consider $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$ and $C=A$, define $f:A\to B$ by $f(1)=1$ and $g:B\to C$ as $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=1$, then $g\circ f$ is clearly $1-1$ but $g$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f:\{0\}\to \Bbb R$ by $f(0) = 0$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ by $g(x) = x^2$.

> All you can say is that $g$ is one-to-one on the range of $f$.